# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Printing causes any application to crash

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, server-crashes

We have a problem when trying to print on a new virtual machine using windows server 2012 r2 on all (ipv4) network printers.

When we try to print from Adobe Reader, SQL server management and all other application we installed the application crashes (i.e. adobe reader has stopped working).
When we try to print from notepad or paint we have not problem and it print  normally.

It's a big problem cause it is the server that run management information systems and its prints.
Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The following tools are commonly used to troubleshoot Printing issues in Windows which can be helpful: 1) Event Viewer 2) Windows Debugging Tools 3)Application Verifier - If you want to read more about this then I'll provide you the link for your solution.

Comment: print your pdf **as a image** to resolve your issue.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried to do to fix the problem and what the results are. Start with the Windows Event logs. When you try to print from Adobe Reader and Adobe Reader crashes what is in the Application Windows Event Log?

Comment: Adobe Reader is notoriously horrible.  Try a different pdf viewer and see if you still have issue.

Comment: In event viewer adobe error:
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0xcccccccc

Comment: Hi Selah, I would be very grateful if you can link me some guides for WDT /  Application verifier

Comment: I tried to create another Vm with a fresh Windows 2012 R2, i installed the printer... and same probleam occured.

Comment: Ah, i could be more clear. Adobe reader crash when i click on print, the print menù never appears

Comment: I searched about your query and all I got is this which will help you. solution: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13308.troubleshooting-windows-server-2012-printing.aspx Hope it works for you. Thanks & regards Selah